# Which Framework/Package to use for Swift Linux that also can be used for Vapor

Tags: swift, linux, http, vapor

I've written an API-Wrapper for an external REST-API. This wrapper provides iOS and macOS-Apps an convenient access to that API.
But I want to expand that API-Wrapper to Vapor on Linux.
Linux (RaspiOS with 64-Bit) has Swift 5.5 running (without [swift-corelibs-foundation](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation)) so URLSession is not available. I tried [SwiftyRequest](https://github.com/Kitura/SwiftyRequest) and [AsyncHTTPClient](https://github.com/swift-server/async-http-client) but both did not play well with Vapor. E.g. `wait()` can't be used with Vapor and `whenComplete()` draws error * underlying error: uncleanShutdown* while `syncShutdown` can't be used for the same reason as `wait()`

So I'm stuck with connecting to the API.

What would be a proper way to perform the request that works standalone and with vapor?

Answer (score 1):

Vapor has a `Client` protocol you should use if using Vapor but that's built on top of AsyncHTTPClient. You're correct in that you can't use `wait()` if you're on an event loop but you should use future handlers (or even better the new async/await APIs). What part is reporting unclean shutdown? If that's coming from AsyncHTTPClient then the API you're calling isn't closing the connection properly but you can configure it to ignore this.

As an aside, Vapor requires Foundation so you'll need that to be able to build it anyway

Comment: It's correct that vapor uses Foundation and Swift for Linux also has Foundation implemented but on the Linux Side Swift (especially the pre build packages for piOS) lacking certain parts e.g. `URLSession`. That's why I have to use an external Framework.

Comment: My problem is that I can't get `AsyncHTTPClient` to work on Vapor as it crashes either with `wait()`/`syncShutdown()` (not allowed in EventLoop) or `whenComplete()` fails because of not shutdown correctly.

Comment: It sounds like you're creating your own client and event loop group - you shouldn't be doing that. Just use `app.client` or `req.client`